# ¿Es posible inicializar un Activity desde un Fragmento en Android?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Tengo este código en un fragmento y deseo iniciar una Actividad:

```
 @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!getUserVisibleHint())
        {
            return;
        }

        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Iniciar Actividad!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Aqui pretendo inicializar la actividad

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddClientActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
```

Prácticamente estoy lamando a un `FloatingButton` que tengo en `MainActivity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que es posible!, si lo deseas realizar dentro de un `Fragment`, usa como contexto el `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`, mediante [**getActivity()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddClientActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

---

incluso como otra opción, estas obteniendo la instancia de `MainActivity`, puedes usar esta como contexto:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
```

de esta forma:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddClientActivity.class);
 mainActivity.startActivity(i);
```